C++ shared_ptr from *this, parent and derived classes
I need to get a shared_ptr from this, which is easy for a parent class. But when you start deriving from this class - the issue is more difficult.
You get this error:
 member 'shared_from_this' found in multiple base classes of different types
        return this->shared_from_this();                     ^
note: member found by ambiguous name lookup

How should I approach this?
#include <memory>

struct AAA : std::enable_shared_from_this<AAA>
{
    auto getA() -> std::shared_ptr<AAA> { return this->shared_from_this(); }
};

struct BBB : AAA, std::enable_shared_from_this<BBB>
{
    auto getB() -> std::shared_ptr<BBB> { return this->shared_from_this(); }
};

EDIT:
The reason for this convoluted code, is that I want my API to be designed in such way that you have setters - that return "self" and then you have chainability. Originally the setters would return a reference to self, but then code looks ugly (see the conversion from a pointer, to a reference):
// Before
auto a = std::make_shared<AAA>();
a->set_attrZ(1)
   .set_attrK(2);

auto b = std::make_shared<BBB>();
b->set_attr1A(1)
   .set_attrB(2)
   .set_callback(()[]{ /* */ });

// After
auto a = std::make_shared<AAA>()
   -> set_attrZ(1)
   -> set_attrK(2);

auto b = std::make_shared<BBB>()
   -> set_attrA(1)
   -> set_attrB(2)
   -> set_callback( ()[]{ /* */ });

// note that in some cases you might not need to maintain the reference - this may download a json from server and handle the data in the callback.
std::make_shared<BBB>()
   -> set_attrA(1)
   -> set_attrB(2)
   -> set_callback( ()[]{ /* */ })
   -> do_some_work();


Why does BBB need to inherit from std::enable_shared_from_this when its base class already does?

I think the close votes here are missing the underlying problem that caused OP to ask this question. A std::static_pointer_cast is what they're looking for. I was halfway through answering with the solution, but got locked out.

I'm not certain the duplicate question this answer was originally closed with adequately asnswers the op's question.  Op is asking about how to have shared_from_this work across an inheritance tree, which is slightly more nuanced that asking about how to handle a duplicate function name across different base classes.

@paddy "A std::static_pointer_cast is what they're looking for." -- That's not what I get from the question. I understand that would be an answer to a logical follow-up question, but the question as asked is about the ambiguity caused by having two enable_shared_from_this base classes. Assuming there is a reason for having two such bases (I did ask for clarification about that), the duplicate I picked explains how to resolve the ambiguity.

@elcuco "condescending answers like I got here" -- First off, you got a comment, not answers. Second, sorry if you think asking for a clarification is condescending, but I meant what I wrote. Maybe you have a reason to inherit from enable_shared_from_this twice. Maybe you don't. I don't know. Without a clarification in the question, I have to assume you do have a reason, so the linked duplicate applies. If you edit the question to explain what your real goal is and mention that you do not necessarily need to inherit from enable_shared_from_this twice, then I'd re-open it.

Normally, your most-basic base-class derives from enabled_shared_from_this, and you just add functions to the derived classes to cast the result to the type that you need.

@ChristianStieber that was my original impression (first time using this API). What happens when I need a shared ptr from the derived class (see BBB on my example). I am open to suggestions.

Note for the edit: "chained" setters and inheritance are a massive pain, as you will have to overload everything in every subclass, otherwise b->setAProp() has returned you an AAA, not a BBB, or you make everything an explicit object member function

I think you want:
struct BBB : AAA
{
    auto getB() -> std::shared_ptr<BBB> { 
        auto spA = getA();
        auto spB = std::static_pointer_cast<BBB>(spA);
        return spB;
    }
};

Or this:
struct BBB : AAA, std::enable_shared_from_this<BBB>
{
    auto getB() -> std::shared_ptr<BBB> { 
        std::enable_shared_from_this<BBB>* sftB = this;
        return sftB->shared_from_this();
    }
};

I like the former better than the latter. The former doesn't create such a muddled inheritance tree.

Another solution (which was the one I implemented):
struct BBB : AAA, std::enable_shared_from_this<BBB>
{
    auto getB() -> std::shared_ptr<BBB> { 
         return this->std::enable_shared_from_this<BBB>::shared_from_this(); 
    }
};

Or alternative - without re-inheriting in BBB:
struct BBB : AAA
{
    auto getB() -> std::shared_ptr<BBB> { 
         return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Button>(this->shared_from_this());
    }
};


